# Dropping columns from an orthogonal design matrix?

Tags: anova, markov-chain-montecarlo, categorical-encoding, orthogonal

Hello:  I’m working with a three factor (ANOVA) design that I wish to use in an MCMC chain to estimate the parameters for the main effects and treatment interactions.  I wish to run MCMC analyses using a number of different response variables, but using the same set of explanatory variables (factors+treatments).  I am using reference level coding, i.e. a specific combination of each factor’s treatment level is represented by the model’s intercept.  I’ve had difficulty getting the chains to converge, and have found that orthogonalizing the design matrix helps (using SAS “orthref” coding).  I am explicitly creating my design matrix prior to the MCMC run, rather than letting the software generate it.  I’ve found that I get better MCMC performance if I set the reference (treatment) levels for each of the factors to be the specific combination of treatments that has the most data for that response variable.  In other words,  for each response variable that I run my intercept will represent a different combination of factor treatments.

My question:  Can I:

1. Create one “master” orthogonal design matrix with a dummy treatment for each factor’s reference treatment to represent the intercept.  This would leave me with a design matrix having a column for each factor’s treatments (not one less than the number of treatments), along with columns for the interactions.
2. Then, for each run with a response variable, could I then drop/exclude the columns from the “master” design matrix for the combination of treatment levels that I wish to have represent the intercept for that response variable?

More succinctly:  Once I’ve created the overall “master” orthogonal design matrix, is it acceptable to omit various columns from that design matrix when running the MCMC for a specific response variable, and to drop different columns for each run with a different response variable?